Running pre-commit on all changed files
After installing the hooks in my projects, I was faced with the issue that atomic commits are now difficult, since I have changes which are unstaged but their head version still includes the issues.
I know that I am able to run pre-commit run --all-files, but how do I tell git that it has to run the hooks with --all-file when executing git commit?
EDIT:
---
repos:
  - repo: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint.git
    rev: v24.7.0
    hooks:
      - id: ansible-lint
        name: Ansible-lint
        description: This hook runs ansible-lint.
        entry: python3 -m ansiblelint -v --force-color
        language: python
        # do not pass files to ansible-lint, see:
        # https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/issues/611
        pass_filenames: false
        always_run: true
        additional_dependencies:
          # https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit/issues/1526
          # If you want to use specific version of ansible-core or ansible, feel
          # free to override `additional_dependencies` in your own hook config
          # file.
          - ansible-core>=2.13.3


I think you're confused.  pre-commit runs on staged files while committing.  --all-files is every file in the repo which is wasteful at commit time and not supported.

In my case it also runs on files which are not staged but on the files verions which are on the HEAD. I have extended my question with my specific pre-commit config, which is the unchanged version from ansible-lint

yeah ansible-lint doesn't really play nicely -- it's all or nothing.  I recommend spending a commit getting it passing before introducing it
